# Whats Wrong With This Assignment?

Tags: python

I am new to python I have 2.6 python interpreter

What is wrong with this statement ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

pass = 12
print (pass)
```

Error

```
 ./hello.py
  File "./hello.py", line 3
    pass = 'pass'
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Lots of tutorial seem to do this (same syntax) and why is this error ?

Comment: `pass` is a keyword in Python and can't be used as a variable.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

Comment: "Lots of tutorials seem to do this (same syntax)." I'd like to see a link to a single one!

Comment: why doesnt python say that it is a keyword and cannot be used?

Comment: Because syntax errors happen very early in the process the Python interpreter uses to figure out what your code means, and if it contains one 99.9% of the time it is just a typo that the programmer will immediately know how to fix. It doesn't study your code's next few and previous few steps to try to figure out what you were trying to do instead.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, [here's one](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html). Without knowing about `pass`, a much more advanced concept than `width = 20`, they are the same syntax.

Comment: Feel free to delete the qn if it can save my points but I dont agree that it is intuitive as pass is not a keyword in any other language and the error doesnt say that Iam over loading a keyword. How is a python newbie supposed to guess?

Comment: @resultsway Are you using an IDE? Syntax highlighting is usually what will save you from this type of mistake. (Notice how in your code sample it is blue here on SO.)

Comment: @askewchan I see where you're coming from, but I have to disagree. `pass` is not an advanced concept, Python is not "stupid" for being perhaps the only language with such a keyword, and `pass = 'x'` is not the same syntax as `x = 'pass'`. Consider how this question would look if it were complaining about assigning to `def` instead. Not knowing is one thing. Furiously criticizing parts of the language you don't understand is quite another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`pass`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) is keyword in python and can't be used as a variable.

Change your `pass` to another name.

Comment: This is pretty intuitive. Please close question instead.

Comment: why doesnt python say that it is a keyword and cannot be used?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi It is not intuitive which language has pass as a keyword ? and the stupid thing is showing invalid syntax and pointing to assignment operator

Comment: @resultsway "Which language has pass as a keyword?" Python. "stupid... showing invalid syntax and pointing to the assignment operator." That's **literally exactly** where the error occurs. `pass`? Fine. Assign to pass? Now we got a problem.

Comment: @resultsway, pass is valid syntax, putting an `=` after is not

Answer (score 2):

`pass` is a keyword so you cannot use it as a variable name, you can see all the python keywords using the keyword module:

```
In [25]: import keyword
In [26]: keyword.kwlist
Out[26]: 
['and',
 'as',
 'assert',
 'break',
 'class',
 'continue',
 'def',
 'del',
 'elif',
 'else',
 'except',
 'exec',
 'finally',
 'for',
 'from',
 'global',
 'if',
 'import',
 'in',
 'is',
 'lambda',
 'not',
 'or',
 'pass',
 'print',
 'raise',
 'return',
 'try',
 'while',
 'with',
 'yield']
```

Any word appearing in the kwlist is a python keyword, none of which can be used as variable names.